# Absolute positioning of a GWT TextArea in IE?

Tags: html, gwt, textarea, word-wrap

```
TextArea textarea1 = TextArea.wrap(DOM.getElementById("t"));
```

In onModuleLoad() I wrote 2 lines given below:

```
textAreaStyle = "position:absolute;top:0px;";

textarea1.getElement().setAttribute("style", textAreaStyle);
```

In Firefox and Chrome, the textarea is placed in absolute position and 0px from top, but
in IE the textarea remains at its default position.

Is there a bug in my code?

Comment: Also, it's not really helpful to have the title of your question just be the tags in a different order. I've edited your question's title to be more descriptive, so more people will look at it, and potentially answer.

Comment: from this time i will do as your rule

Comment: IIRC, you should set two coordinates: top/bottom *and* left/right. So, the style should be `"position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"`. But I can't check it atm, so I'll leave that up to you ;)

Comment: i did but no result.still problem.if you time pls check yourself